# What is a proper use of downcasting?

Tags: c#, object-oriented

Downcasting means casting from a base class (or interface) to a subclass or leaf class.

An example of a downcast might be if you cast from `System.Object` to some other type.

Downcasting is unpopular, maybe a code smell: Object Oriented doctrine is to prefer, for example, defining and calling virtual or abstract methods instead of downcasting.

- What, if any, are good and proper use cases for downcasting? That is, in what circumstance(s) is it appropriate to write code that downcasts?
- If your answer is "none", then why is downcasting supported by the language?

Comment: What you describe is usually called "downcasting". Armed with that knowledge, could you do some more research of your own first, and explain why existing reasons that you found are not sufficient? TL;DR: downcasting breaks static typing, but sometimes a type system is too restrictive. So it's sensible for a language to offer safe downcasting.

Comment: Do you mean downcasting? Upcasting would be up through the class hierarchy, i.e. from subclass to superclass, as opposed to downcasting, from superclass to subclass ...

Comment: My apologies: you're right. I edited the question to rename "upcast" to "downcast".

Comment: @amon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting gives "convert to string" as an example (which .Net supports using a virtual `ToString`); its other example is "Java containers" because Java doesn't support generics (which C# does). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524197/downcast-and-upcast says what downcasting *is*, but without examples of when it's *appropriate*.

Comment: @ChrisW That's `before Java had support for generics`, not `because Java doesn't support generics`. And amon pretty much gave you the answer - when the type system you're working with is too restrictive and you're not in a position to change it.

Comment: @Ordous I don't understand that answer: could you give some example[s]?

Comment: @ChrisW, The "string" example in Wikipedia is very weak.  It basically just shows a round about way of converting a reference to a `String` into a reference to a `String`.  Not much point in it.  A better example would be a function that operates in some generic way on an `Animal`, but then does something special if the `Animal` happens to be a `Dog`.

Comment: @jameslarge If you know any references which give good examples of downcasting, I'd like to know. I looked at the first few pages of https://www.google.fr/search?q=downcasting+c%23 and it only returned trivial examples, using Shape and so on, to explain what it *is* but not when to use it.

Comment: @ChrisW, The time to use downcasting is when you need to work around a defect in a broken design because you have limited time in which to solve some problem that the design failed to anticipate.

Comment: Whenever you use `findViewById()` in Android you usually have to cast the result.

Comment: It's a fundamental part of polymorphism. You should try to use the most specific interface, abstract class, or superclass possible, but there are definitely real-world cases for objects.

MVC has ViewData and ViewBag
ASP.NET (and by extension MVC / Web.API) can store reference types in Session, which are pulled out as objects.

Use the is / as constructs to check and cast the type. Use a generic if it works for your scenario. 

Another example: for example, a List<T> can only contain T. It cannot contain T1 and T2. You could make List<object> or just use an ArrayList for a mixed set.

Comment: it smells like homework

Comment: Perfect example of legitimate downcasting: When needing to adjust or add data annotations on a parent class and the class you are working working with is a member of another class. Not legal in C#, but Swift provides "as!" and "as?" operators for just such exceptions..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Here are some proper uses of downcasting.

And I respectfully ***vehemently* disagree** with others here who say the use of downcasts is *definitely* a code smell, because I believe there is no other reasonable way to solve the corresponding problems.

#### `Equals`:

```
class A
{
    // Nothing here, but if you're a C++ programmer who dislikes object.Equals(object),
    // pretend it's not there and we have abstract bool A.Equals(A) instead.
}
class B : A
{
    private int x;
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var casted = other as B;  // cautious downcast (dynamic_cast in C++)
        return casted != null && this.x == casted.x;
    }
}
```

#### `Clone`:

```
class A : ICloneable
{
    // Again, if you dislike ICloneable, that's not the point.
    // Just ignore that and pretend this method returns type A instead of object.
    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();  // some sane default behavior, whatever
    }
}
class B : A
{
    private int[] x;
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var copy = (B)base.Clone();  // known downcast (static_cast in C++)
        copy.x = (int[])this.x.Clone();  // oh hey, another downcast!!
        return copy;
    }
}
```

#### `Stream.EndRead/Write`:

```
class MyStream : Stream
{
    private class AsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        // ...
    }
    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult other)
    {
        return Blah((AsyncResult)other);  // another downcast (likely ~static_cast)
    }
}
```

If you're going to say these are code smells, you need to provide better solutions for them (even if they are avoided due to inconvenience). I don't believe better solutions exist.

Comment: "Code smell" does not mean "this design is *definitely bad*" it means "this design is *suspicious*". That there are language features that are *inherently suspicious* is a matter of pragmatism on the part of the language author

Comment: @Caleth: And my entire point is that these designs come up all the time, and that there is **absolutely nothing** inherently suspicious about the designs I have shown, and hence the casting is not a code smell.

Comment: @Caleth I disagree. Code smell, to me, means that the code is bad or, at the very least, could be improved.

Comment: `Equals` is suspicious, because you switch between reference equality and value equality, or if you have an implementation with value equality all the way down you end up with `new C().Equals(new B())` returning true because the `A` parts match. That *might* be wrong, or it *might* be right, but it will likely confuse *someone*

Comment: @Caleth: What in the world are you talking about? How could `new C().Equals(new B())` return `true`? `Equals` is something that needs to be overridden in subclasses to work correctly. Downcasts are irrelevant to this.

Comment: `Stream` is suspicious, because you assume that no-one will ever pass an `IAsyncResult` from anywhere else

Comment: how do you implement `Equals` for `class C : B` and `class D : B`, such that you surprise no-one?

Comment: @Caleth: `Equals` and `Stream` are *suspicious* now?! Have you *never* programmed in C#...?! I was busy writing you a much more nuanced response, but your claims are getting too preposterous for me to continue writing that response anymore. Yeah, sure, my designs are awful. Sorry, I don't know better. So how about **you** enlighten **me** how **you** would *"implement `Equals` such that you surprise no-one"* without downcasts? I'm all eyes/ears and I would love to learn from your perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, they are *suspicious*. No, they are not *bad*. In an *ideal world* the type system would stop you from passing an `IAsyncResult` to `EndRead` that came from a difference **instance** of `Stream`'s `BeginRead`. In a less ideal world (which is still better than what we have) the type system would stop you passing an `IAsyncResult` that came from a different **subclass** of `Stream`'s `BeginRead`.

Comment: And I wouldn't have a global polymorphic `Equal`s *at all*. Where I needed a specific (potentially polymorphic) equivalence relation, I would use an instance of `IEqualityComparer<B>` that fit *those specific needs*

Comment: @Caleth: OK, so here's the usual polymorphic example. How would you use `IEqualityComparer` polymorphically while avoiding downcasts like you claim? `class Expression { abstract bool Equals(Expression other); }` `class AdditionExpression : Expression { ... }` `class SubtractionExpression : Expression { ... }` `void Main() { var evaluated = new Dictionary<Expression, Value>(); /* proceed to discover & evaluate expressions */}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73784/discussion-between-caleth-and-mehrdad).

Comment: Alright, [I’ve reimplemented your code without downcasting](https://gist.github.com/klmr/30b8950658bd3991d2b722281f39799c) (note the discussion!). But now I have to say that, although the code gives a solution that works without downcasting, I’m no longer convinced that downcasting is generally avoidable. It’s certainly not *practically* avoidable.

Comment: A classical case of "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail". What this demonstrates is that C#'s type system is too limited to fully express the intention here. `object.Equals` in Java or .NET is one of its worst design decisions (shortly after the whole clone() debacle). You might want to look at say Haskell or similar languages to demonstrate ways to solve the issues at hand quite nicely.

Comment: @Voo: Way to criticize with something completely irrelevant. I'm only answering the question of when you would want to downcast, not evangelize for Haskell and tell the C# designers how comparably awful their type system is. And like I said, if you dislike `object.Equals(object)`, `pretend it's not there and we have abstract bool A.Equals(A) instead`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks! But you're not reimplementing the same functionality -- the entire caveat here was that `Equals` needs to be polymorphic. If you always know the derived type of whatever you're comparing then obviously you can downcast, but my entire point was that's frequently not the case, e.g. [in the classic Expression example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366592/what-is-a-proper-use-of-downcasting/366666?noredirect=1#comment799963_366666). (Unless you're handling that and I'm misunderstanding?)

Comment: @Mehrdad Your opinion seems to be that code smells have to be the fault of application programmers. Why? Not every code smell has to be an actual problem or have a solution. A code smell according to Martin Fowler is simply "a surface indication that usually corresponds to a deeper problem in the system" `object.Equals` fits that description quite well (try to correctly provide an equals contract in a superclass that allows subclasses to correctly implement it - it's absolutely non-trivial). That as application programmers we can't solve it (in some cases we can avoid it) is a different topic.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You cannot treat all downcasts with suspicion simply because there are too many that are acceptable. It would be like turning on the most pedantic warnings in an existing project - unless there are already no pedantic warnings (because you fixed them all), it tends to drown out the more important warnings that really should notice.

Comment: @immibis: thanks, I think your first sentence summed it up perfectly.

Comment: @Voo: a language feature being a code smell does *not* mean the language designer might have a problem in their design. It means *you* might have a problem in *your* design. At this point you're outputting such utter nonsense that I can't take you seriously anymore. It's very clear you're saying something just for the sake of having said something and left your mark.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: oops, just noticed a typo in my reply (though I'm guessing you already noticed): *"then obviously you can downcast"* was supposed to say *"then obviously you can **avoid** a downcast"*.

Comment: @Mehrdad Well let's see what one of the original language designers has to say about Equals.. `Object.Equals is horrid. Equality computation in C# is completely messed up` (Eric's comment on his answer). It's funny how you don't want to reconsider your opinion even when one of the lead designers of the language itself tells you you're wrong.

Comment: @Mehrdad Right, that’s why I wanted a concrete example … my code solves the problem posed in your answer (while trying to use a more illustrative example). Yes, something like the `Expression` pattern isn’t solved by this, as I discussed in the document accompanying the code. That would be solved by a visitor (and this is in fact the “established solution” there), with all the caveats you mentioned (i.e. visitors work well on sum types, but are hard to extend).

Comment: @immibis I’m not sure you’re making a good argument here because I always work with the strictest set of warnings enabled (but obviously from the start) and I strongly argue that this is *the* correct way of working. That said, see [Voo’s comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366592/what-is-a-proper-use-of-downcasting/366666?noredirect=1#comment800116_366666): Code smell points to an underlying problem, but it’s not necessarily fixable by the application programmer, similar to the usage of `goto`.

Comment: @Mehrdad It's simple: You seem to think that since `object.Equals` is part of the language it cannot be a code smell. By that argument using `goto` in C++ or `with` in JavaScript is great too. Yes as a pragmatic programmer we will have to accept code smells sometimes, but that doesn't mean they are not code smells. When using them, you better be particularly careful, it might also mean that you should rethink your design to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yeah, basically. Great that we're on the same page. :-) And I should mention I'm also with you on the warning example not being the best one, I do try to enable most warnings too (which is why I only endorsed his first sentence and not the rest =P). But I do think while his point still stands -- [see my comments here (multiple)](/questions/366592?noredirect=1#comment800123_366601) on code smells and associated case-by-case analysis. There's just too many huge *classes* of problems in which a downcast is *the* accepted solution to call it a code smell.

Comment: **Please avoid extended discussions in the comments section.  Additional comments should be taken to chat.  Thank you.**

Comment: I was tempted to accept [TKK's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366616/19237) and/or [mmathis's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366596/19237), but this answer (`Equals` especially) may be the most common and fundamental example.

Comment: Not good solution!

Comment: @Voo What other statically typed languages are able to avoid this problem? I'd love to see how Haskell deals with it, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 149):

> Downcasting is unpopular, maybe a code smell

I disagree. Downcasting is *extremely popular*; a huge number of real-world programs contain one or more downcasts. And it is not *maybe* a code smell. It is *definitely* a code smell.  **That's why the downcasting operation is required to be manifest in the text of the program**.  It's so that you can more easily notice the smell and spend code review attention on it.

> in what circumstance[s] is it appropriate to write code which downcasts?

In any circumstance where:

- you have *a 100% correct knowledge* of a fact about the runtime type of an expression that is more specific than the compile-time type of the expression, and
- you need to take advantage of that fact in order to use a capability of the object not available on the compile-time type, and
- it is a better use of time and effort to write the cast than it is to refactor the program to eliminate either of the first two points.

If you can cheaply refactor a program so that either the runtime type can be deduced by the compiler, or to refactor the program so that you don't need the capability of the more derived type, then do so. Downcasts were added to the language for those circumstances where it is *hard* and *expensive* to thus refactor the program.

> why is downcasting supported by the language?

C# was invented by pragmatic programmers who have jobs to do, *for* pragmatic programmers who have jobs to do. The C# designers are not OO purists. And the C# type system is not perfect; by design it underestimates the restrictions that can be placed on the runtime type of a variable.

Also, downcasting is very safe in C#. We have a strong guarantee that the downcast will be verified at runtime and if it cannot be verified then the program does the right thing and crashes. This is wonderful; it means that if your 100% correct understanding of type semantics turns out to be 99.99% correct, then your program works 99.99% of the time and crashes the rest of the time, instead of behaving unpredictably and corrupting user data 0.01% of the time.

---

EXERCISE: There is at least one way to produce a downcast in C# *without* using an explicit cast operator. Can you think of any such scenarios? Since these are also potential code smells, what design factors do you think went into the design of a feature that could produce a downcast crash without having a manifest cast in the code?

Comment: The most common use case for downcasting is when we you are dealing with a property change callback in your DependencyProperty.  This is really important if you have any custom controls.

Comment: Thank you for answering. **"extremely popular"** funny :-) Are there any *good* examples I should know of? **"manifest in the text of the program"** I don't know: it's just an identifier in parentheses, not easy to Find in Files (unlike C++, which evolved to using even-more-evident xxx_`cast<>()` instead). **"Can you think of any such scenarios?"** Using the `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: @ChrisW: Yep, `dynamic` is one. `dynamic` is essentially `object` where a cast is inserted for you at runtime that casts to the runtime type, which is safe. There are also ways in C# to introduce downcasts that can fail at runtime; see if you can think of any.

Comment: Remember those posters in high school on the walls "What is popular is not always right, what is right is not always popular?" You thought they were trying to keep you from doing drugs or getting pregnant in high school but they were actually warnings about the dangers of technical debt.

Comment: ... now I'm stuck wondering about those other ways.  I know some in Java (e.g. the [combination of generics and vararg methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html)), but my understanding is that C# managed to avoid that particular issue.  Unfortunately, I've not spent enough time working in C# to know it in enough depth to figure any out...

Comment: @EricLippert, the foreach statement, of course. This was done before IEnumerable was generic, right?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: Correct! `foreach` introduces several casts, the most interesting of which is the cast to the loop variable type. And yes, it was put in there before the days of generics. Had generics been in the type system from the beginning, probably the foreach loop would not have inserted a cast.

Comment: The compound assignment operators `+=` and so on introduce casts but they are *representation changing* casts and not casts up and down a type hierarchy. For example, the compound assignment in `byte b; ...  b += 1;` is processed as `b = (byte)((int)b+1);` but that is not an example of a downcast in the sense of this question because `byte` and `int` do not have a supertype/subtype relationship.

Comment: There is an *undocumented* scenario where the C# compiler introduces a downcast, involving interop. Anyone know what it is? (Hint: is it ever possible for `B b = new B();` to throw an invalid conversion exception *on the assignment to b?*)

Comment: There is also a scenario where you can put a cast operator in a program and a downcast happens but *not to the type in the cast operator*. What is it?

Comment: @EricLippert With numeric types, will `short x = 1; long y = (int)x;` generate a cast from `short` to `long` without a cast to `int`?

Comment: @EricLippert, or is it because of auto-boxing?

Comment: @EricLippert I know from using Excel interop that you can "`new`" an interop interface. So you can say `B b = new B();` even though `B` is an interface. Underneath this is really creating (I think) a .NET wrapper class around (I think) a COM class. But... that's not really a downcast, it's more of an upcast, so not sure how close I am to guessing.

Comment: (Maybe the downcast is from the COM type to the .NET type? Which could throw if you didn't implement the interop type properly? I probably don't know enough to guess correctly.)

Comment: (Reading, it sounds like the cast is from `System.__ComObject` to the interop interface. This can fail if the COM object does not provide enough information/is not configured properly for this kind of usage.)

Comment: @DaveCousineau: Correct, doing `new` on an interop interface gives you back an instance of the coclass, and it query-interfaces for the interface, which can fail at runtime. You're right that it's a kind of half-upcast, half-downcast. Either way, it is super weird that `new B()` can result in an error when attempting to convert to `B`.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser: The optimizer would be within its rights to do so, since there is no possible visible difference.  Also, shorts need not be stored in a memory location or register of short size; it might already be integer or long sized when the conversion to long happens.

Comment: @EricLippert "There is also a scenario where you can put a cast operator in a program and a downcast happens but not to the type in the cast operator. What is it?" Unboxing a value type? `object o = 3; int i = (int)o;` Feeling a tad iffy on my internal reasoning.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: Nope. Suppose we have `class A {}
class B : A {}
class C{
   public static explicit operator C(B m) { return new D(); }
}
class D : C { }` and then `A a = new B(); D d = (D)a;`.  The compiler generates the code as `(D)(C)(B)a`, so we have an upcast from `A` to `B` not manifest in the source code text, and then an upcast from `C` to `D` that *is* in the source code.

Comment: Note that the compiler never chains *user defined conversions* like this but it *can* put a built-in conversion on *either side* of a user-defined conversion. In the example I gave, a built-in conversion goes on both sides. We can also introduce explicit nullable value type conversions in this way if the types are value types.

Comment: @EricLippert This is really interesting, I didn't know you could chain user-defined and built-in casts this way. It must be a headache to debug if it ever happens in real code, tho.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: I can assure you it was a headache to implement. Particularly since there are bugs in the algorithm that must be maintained for backwards compatibility with existing programs that should have been errors. See the sources for details; I left copious notes. :-)

Comment: This explanation made my day. As a teacher, I often get asked why C# is designed in this or that way, and my answers are often based on motivations you and your colleagues have shared here and on your blogs. It's often a bit harder to answer the follow-up question "But _whyyyyy_?!". And here I find the perfect follow-up answer: "C# was invented by pragmatic programmers who have jobs to do, for pragmatic programmers who have jobs to do.". :-) Thank you @EricLippert!

Comment: Downcasts may indicate some kind of design problem someplace, but not necessarily at the point of the cast.  Something like the downcast in `Enumerable<T>.Count`, for example, is necessary because `IEnumerable<T>` lacks a means of asking whether the underlying collection knows its count, or asking the collection for its count if it knows.

Comment: Aside: Obviously in my comment above I meant to say we have a *downcast* from A to B. I really dislike the use of "up" and "down" and "parent" and "child" when navigating a class hierarchy and I get them wrong all the time in my writing. The relationship between the types is a superset/subset relationship, so why there should be a direction up or down associated with it, I don't know. And don't even get me started on "parent". The parent of Giraffe is not Mammal, the parent of Giraffe are Mr. and Mrs. Giraffe.

Comment: @supercat: That's a good point which I decided to not go into here. The use cases for `is` and `as` tests are those where you're legit not sure what the type is, and you can maybe do something special if you can find out at runtime, whereas I think of downcasts as being used when you have a *proof* that the expression will be of the given type.

Comment: @EricLippert this was fascinating; is any of this easily accessible elsewhere? Given that comments are temporary, it would be awesome to be able to refer back to this reliably.

Comment: @Dannnno: These sorts of things have come up on my blog from time to time.  This series in particular is germane to this discussion: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/16/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c/  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/18/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c-part-two/   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/04/20/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c-part-three/ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/08/whats-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators/ and so on.

Comment: @EricLippert: I generally love your answers and your insights (in fact just today I saw another one of your blog posts I loved), but this may be the first time I *vehemently* disagree with you. I'm completely shocked that you wrote *"it is not maybe a code smell. It is definitely a code smell"* -- I hope I'm missing or misunderstanding something, because it just seems *so* wrong. Are you seriously saying that implementing/overriding, say, `object.Equals(object)` is now considered a code smell?

Comment: @Mehrdad No, he isn’t. He’s saying that the *existence* of `object.Equals(object)` inside `System.Object` is code smell. But given that that’s now its signature (rather than a generic one), implementing it isn’t code smell. See also supercat’s previous comment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: That's absurd though. And focusing on `object.Equals`'s existence (which C++ists like you and me would argue against) is completely missing the point. It's *impossible* to have an `Superclass.Equals` method that works polymorphically without having downcasts somewhere, so you(/Eric) are saying that merely being able to check for equality of two objects whose exact derived types you do not know at the point of the call is a code smell? And the same with `Stream.EndRead`, `Superclass.Clone`, etc. -- all of those are signs of code smells somewhere in the codebase? Really?

Comment: @Mehrdad Why would it be absurd? — And checking for polymorphic equality works perfectly well without downcasting if you’re willing to go the extra mile and implement an appropriate visitor. — Of course most people *wouldn’t* be willing to go the extra mile but (a) that’s why Eric said C# is written by pragmatic people for pragmatic people, and (b) you very rarely need to do this; in ~99% of cases, either a simple, statically typed function or a virtual function is the correct way of implementing equality comparison.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's absurd because it's literally the accepted way (and I believe the only way) to implement methods like these polymorphically, and these methods **are** implemented, used, and benefited from this way all the time in real code, so saying that their existence is a code smell makes no sense. How would you implement visitors for `Equals` or `Clone`? Maybe it's my lack of sleep betraying me right now but I'm not seeing how you'd do that here. (I don't even see how to do visitors with `EndRead` to be honest, but that might be just me, just focus on the previous ones.)

Comment: @Mehrdad Would you post `object.Equals` as an answer to the question (instead of only a comment), or shall I do it?

Comment: @ChrisW: Good idea, I'll do it, give me a few minutes!

Comment: @ChrisW: Posted. And I'll add more as I think of them.

Comment: @Mehrdad It’s hard to prove a negative. Why don’t you give me an example hierarchy that you think cannot implement `Equals` and `Clone` without downcasting and I’ll see what I can do?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Sure, there's some in [**my answer**](/a/366666/11833).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: While you're busy with that, a couple more notes: (1) Even *with* the visitor pattern, I believe the only way you can avoid a downcast is if the visitor interface exhaustively lists all the types that its implementers could handle a priori. But the classes that it can visit need to know about the visitor, too. So that means the classes in the hierarchy must *all* indirectly know about each other *at compile-time*... which means they aren't run-time polymorphic at all! Which means you probably would have a hard time justifying polymorphic inheritance, especially in C++. (cont'd)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: ...(cont'd) So, based on this, I could probably go so far as to actually argue that cast-less visitors in C++ would be an *anti-pattern*, and that you should really be using discriminated unions, and the only reason it would be acceptable in C# is if the language isn't powerful enough to make that practical. (2) It's not really proving a negative -- if you call this a "code smell", that doesn't merely mean "∃ a better approach". Rather, it implies someone ought to *know* of a better approach to tackle or avoid the problem. If not, you can't declare it a code smell!

Comment: `Object.Equals` is **horrid**. Equality computation in C# is *completely messed up*, far too messed up to explain in a comment. There are so many ways to represent equality; it is very easy to make them inconsistent; it is very easy, in fact *required* to violate the properties required of an equality operator (symmetry, reflexivity and transitivity). Were I designing a type system from scratch today there would be no `Equals` (or `GetHashcode` or `ToString`) on `Object` at all.

Comment: Also, let's stop and think about what a code smell is. It's a pattern that warrants extra scrutiny because it is easily abused, confusing or often wrong in a subtle way. **That's equality in a nutshell.** When I was at Coverity I redesigned several of the equality mistake detectors because there are just *so many* ways to implement equality wrong. Yes it is a code smell; you should *thoroughly* review your implementations of `Equals`, and try to not stray far from accepted patterns.

Comment: @Eric I'd be interested on reading up on the requirement to break symmetry/reflexivity/transitivity for the equality operator, if you've got anything.

Comment: @Rawling: Well that's easy.  Is it a requirement that `a.Equals(b) == b.Equals(a)` always successfully compute to true? Or is attaining that *actually impossible*?  Because in every implementation of `Equals` on a reference type I've ever seen, `a.Equals(b)` is false if `b` is `null`, but `b.Equals(a)` crashes.

Comment: And even without null, if you're implementing `Frob` and you decide that some `Frob`s are equal to some `Blob`s, then achieving `frob.Equals(blob) == blob.Equals(frob)` requires you to coordinate with the author of `Blob`, who might not even be alive anymore. The fundamental problem is that equality should be a multimethod, but is implemented as either a static method or a single dispatch virtual method, and that then imposes all of the knock-on problems.

Comment: @EricLippert, do you think equality of values from different types is reasonable to begin with? Wouldn't it be better to convert to the same type and then compare?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: That's a reasonable idea but it quickly runs into problems. If `Animal` implements an equality operator on `Animal`s and derived class `Giraffe` implements an equality operator on `Giraffe` then what happens when you try to compare a `Giraffe` with a `Tiger`? Hopefully both implementations agree that they are unequal, but which implementation should get used?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: In general I agree with you though. Implementing equality amongst dissimilar types seems like a code smell to me. I would be inclined to implement it as you suggest: implement equality on identical types, and convert one type to another.  However that then leads to its own set of problems. Suppose we have `PolarComplexNumber` and `CartesianComplexNumber` structs. Do you want to have to say `pol.Equals((PolarComplexNumber)car)`?  Seems excessively wordy.

Comment: And then it just gets weird when you add in `==` operators. Should `pol==car` call `PolarComplexNumber.op_Equality` or `CartesianComplexNumber.op_Equality`?  If both exist then the expression is ambiguous.

Comment: @EricLippert I see. This really is a complex problem to think about. Really interesting nonetheless.

Comment: I have to do this a lot with framework objects called by reflection and casting to interfaces.

Comment: @EricLippert: If such an `Equals` is so horrid (and note that the point here wasn't *`object`* having an `Equals` method, but *a **base class** having a **virtual** `Equals` method)*, then how exactly would you implement structural equality [**like this**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366592/what-is-a-proper-use-of-downcasting/366666?noredirect=1#comment799963_366666) without downcasts?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You're overstating my case. I'm not saying "never downcast". I'm saying when possible to avoid cheaply, do so, and when not possible, **review your code extremely carefully because you are now running with scissors**.  Downcasting is *turning off a safety system*.  The points where you turn off a safety system are precisely those where you need to take extra care to ensure correctness.

Comment: @EricLippert: Two points: (1) [Minor] It's not turning off a safety system at all though -- if the downcast fails then it is guaranteed to error. (2) [Major] Your answer comes across much more strongly than your comment. My point has been that "code smell" implies "this isn't the default solution, so you need to do a **case-by-case** analysis", whereas here I'm pointing out here that there are entire **classes** of problems (those for which you use virtual `Equals`, `Clone`, `EndRead`, etc.) for which the default (and only?) solution requires downcasting, so it itself can't be a code smell...

Comment: @EricLippert: Otherwise, you would have to classify *everything* (classes, inheritance, polymorphism, generics, etc.) as a code smell, because they're all misusable, rendering it meaningless. **But,** I would be more than happy to endorse more nuanced positions on *when* it's a code smell. For example, I would say that "downcasting and then calling a virtual method" is a code smell -- it might make sense in obscure cases, but it 100% warrants a case-by-case analysis. Same with "downcasting to *your own class's subclass*" -- that also doesn't make sense in general. And so on and so on.

Comment: @EricLippert: For what it's worth, the specific passages that I'm disputing in your answer are where you say downcasting is *"definitely a code smell"* and that *"Downcasts were added to the language for those circumstances where it is hard and expensive to thus refactor the program."* If you change them to convey that you *do* agree downcasting is the *correct* solution to some problems (and not merely the one that people are forced to choose due to time/cost constraints) then I could agree with your answer.

Answer (score 35):

Event handlers usually have the signature `MethodName(object sender, EventArgs e)`. In some cases it's possible to handle the event without regard for what type `sender` is, or even without using `sender` at all, but in others `sender` must be cast to a more-specific type to handle the event.

For example, you may have two `TextBox`s and you want to use a single delegate to handle an event from each of them. Then you would need to cast `sender` to a `TextBox` so that you could access the necessary properties to handle the event:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox box = (TextBox)sender;
   box.BackColor = string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
}
```

---

Yes, in this example, you could create your own subclass of `TextBox` which did this internally. Not always practical or possible, though.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good example. The `TextChanged` event is a member of `Control` -- I wonder why `sender` isn't of type `Control` instead of type `object`? Also I wonder whether (theoretically) the framework could have redefined the event for each subclass (so that e.g. `TextBox` could have a new version of the event, using `TextBox` as the type of sender) ... that might (or might not) require downcasting (to `TextBox`) inside the `TextBox` implementation (to implement the new event type), but would avoid requiring a downcast in the application code's event handler.

Comment: This is considered acceptable because it is difficult to generalize event handling if every event has its own method signature.  Though I suppose it's an accepted limitation rather than something that's considered best practice because the alternative is actually more troublesome.  If it were possible to start off with a `TextBox sender` rather than an `object sender` without overly complicating the code, I'm sure it would be done.

Comment: @Neil The eventing systems are specifically made to allow forwarding arbitrary data chunks to arbitrary objects. That's nigh impossible to do without runtime-checks for type correctness.

Comment: @Joker_vD Ideally the API would of course support strongly typed callback signatures using generic contravariance. The fact that .NET (overwhelmingly) doesn’t do this is merely due to the fact that generics and covariance were introduced later. — In other words, downcasting here (and, generally, elsewhere) is required due to inadequacies in the language/API, not because it’s fundamentally a good idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure, but how would you store events of arbitrary types in the event queue? Do you just get rid of queuing and go for direct dispatch?

Comment: @Joker_vD Whether you queue or not depends on your application. And whether queues are type erased or strongly typed also depends on the application. For WinForms callbacks there needs to be a time (but it can be deep inside the library) where type erased callbacks are stored in a weakly typed queue, true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : But the question is, is type erasure dependent on queueing? Is there a way to avoid the downcast in all 4 combinations, and if so, what is it? As one option seems to be to have separate queues for each event type, but that leads to a ton of boilerplate.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Well. As I said, type erasure *is* needed. But it needn’t bleed into the user API. Both high-level event handlers and the event invocation code code be strongly typed; and type erasure would happen inside the WinForms library code.

Answer (score 18):

You need downcasting when *something* gives you a supertype and you need to handle it differently depending on the subtype.

```
decimal value;
Donation d = user.getDonation();
if (d is CashDonation) {
     value = ((CashDonation)d).getValue();
}
if (d is ItemDonation) {
     value = itemValueEstimator.estimateValueOf(((ItemDonation)d).getItem());
}
System.out.println("Thank you for your generous donation of $" + value);
```

No, this does not smell good. In a perfect world `Donation` would have an abstract method `getValue` and each implementing subtype would have an appropriate implementation.

But what if these classes are from a library you can not or don't want to change? Then there is no other option.

Comment: This looks like a good time to use the visitor pattern.  Or the `dynamic` keyword which achieves the same result.

Comment: @user2023861 No I think [the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Class_diagram) depends on cooperation from the Donation subclasses -- i.e. Donation needs to declare an abstract `void accept(IDonationVisitor visitor)`, which its subclasses implement by calling specific (e.g. overloaded) methods of `IDonationVisitor`.

Comment: @ChrisW, you're right about that.  Without cooperation, you could still do it using the `dynamic` keyword though.

Comment: In this particular case you could add an estimateValue method to Donation.

Comment: @user2023861: `dynamic` still downcasting, just slower.

Comment: Does anyone know a statically typed OOP language that manages to avoid this? It would be interesting to see how they do it.

Answer (score 12):

To add to [Eric Lippert's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/366601/293020) since I can't comment...

You can often avoid downcasting by refactoring an API to use generics. But [generics weren't added to the language until version 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). So even if your own code doesn't need to support ancient language versions, you may find yourself using legacy classes that aren't parameterized. For example, some class may be defined to carry a payload of type `Object`, which you're forced to cast to the type you know it to actually be.

Comment: Indeed, one might say that generics in Java or C# are essentially just a safe wrapper around storing superclass objects and downcasting to the correct (compiler-checked) subclass before using the elements again. (Unlike C++ templates, which rewrite the code to always use the subclass itself and thus avoid having to downcast – which can boost memory performance, if often at the expense of compilation time and executable size.)

Answer (score 5):

There is a trade-off between static and dynamically typed languages. Static typing gives the compiler a lot of information to be able to make rather strong guarantees about the safety of (parts of) programs. This comes at a cost, however, because not only do you need to know that your program is correct, but you must write the appropriate code to convince the compiler that this is the case. In other words, making claims is easier than proving them.

There are "unsafe" constructs that help you make *unproven* assertions to the compiler. For example, unconditional calls to [`Nullable.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx), unconditional downcasts, `dynamic` objects, etc. They allow you to assert a claim ("I assert that object `a` is a `String`, if I'm wrong, throw a `InvalidCastException`") *without* needing to prove it. This can be useful in cases where proving it is significantly harder than worthwhile.

Abusing this is risky, which is exactly why the explicit downcast notation exists and is mandatory; it's [syntactic salt](http://wiki.c2.com/?SyntacticSalt) meant to draw attention to an unsafe operation. The language *could* have been implemented with implicit downcasting (where the inferred type is unambiguous), but that would hide this unsafe operation, which is not desirable.

Comment: I guess I'm asking, then, for some example[s] of where/when it's necessary or desirable (i.e. good practice) to make this kind of "unproven assertion".

Comment: How about casting the result of a reflection operation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3255716/3141234

Answer (score 3):

Downcasting is considered bad for a couple of reasons. Primarily I think because it's anti-OOP.

OOP would really like it if you never ever had to downcast as its ''raison-d'etre'' is that polymorphism means you don't have to go

```
if(object is X)
{
    //do the thing we do with X's
}
else
{
    //of the thing we do with Y's
}
```

you just do

```
x.DoThing()
```

and the code auto-magically does the right thing.

There are some 'hard' reasons not to downcast:

- In C++ it is slow.
- You get a runtime error if you choose the wrong type.

But the alternative to downcasting in some scenarios can be pretty ugly.

The classic example is message processing, where you don't want to add the processing function to the object, but keep it in the message processor. I then have a tonne of `MessageBaseClass` in an array to process, but I also need each one by subtype for correct processing.

You can use Double Dispatch to get around the problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)... But that also has its issues. Or you can just downcast for some simple code at the risk of those hard reasons.

But this was before Generics were invented. Now you can avoid downcasting by providing a type where the details specified later.

`MessageProccesor<T>` can vary its method parameters and return values by the specified type but still provide generic functionality

Of course no-one is forcing you to write OOP code and there are plenty of language features that are provided but frowned upon, such as reflection.

Comment: I doubt it's slow in C++, especially if you `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: "Message-processing" -- I think of that as meaning e.g. casting [`lParam`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2515261/49942) to something specific. I'm not sure that's a good C# example, though.

Comment: @ChrisW - well, yes, `static_cast` is always fast ... but isn't guaranteed not to fail in undefined ways if you make a mistake and the type *isn't* what you're expecting.

Comment: @Jules: That's completely beside the point.

Comment: @Mehrdad, it exactly the point. to do the equivalent c# cast in c++ is slow. and this is the traditional reason against casting. the alternate static_cast is not equivalent and considered the worse choice due to the undefined behaviour

Comment: @Ewan: No, it's missing the point. For starters, you don't even have the option of using `dynamic_cast` in C++ unless the class has virtual functions, so there doesn't exist *any* exactly equivalent functionality to C#'s, period. Second, if you avoid C++ features because of UB then you're gonna have to avoid incrementing your i's and dereferencing your p's too. And third, "downcasting" as a concept doesn't require a type-check; that's something extra that C#'s cast and C++'s `dynamic_cast` do. *Oh, but the question was specific to C#*, you complain? OK, but then your C++ note is irrelevant.

Comment: @Mehrdad you can dynamic cast anything polymorphic in c++, so its a match for the c# objects in the example. The reason I mention c++ in a c# tagged question is its the historical reason for the 'down cast is slow' thinking, the new c# 'as' casting is faster but I didn't want to get into a huge discussion about which version of which language has performance issues with which type of down casting. Down casting is traditionally a slow operation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all before said, imagine a Tag property that is of type object. It provides a way for you to store an object of your choice in another object for later use as you need. You need downcast this property.

In general, not using something until today is not always an indication of something useless ;-)

Comment: Yes see for example [What use is the Tag property in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3823669/49942). In one of the answers there, someone wrote, *I used to use it to input instructions to the user in Windows Forms applications. When the control GotFocus event triggered, the instructions Label.Text property was assigned the value of my control Tag property which contained the instruction string.* I guess an alternative way to 'extend' the `Control` (instead of using `object Tag` property) would be to create a `Dictionary<Control, string>` in which to store the label for each control.

Comment: I like this answer because `Tag` is a public property of a .Net framework class, which shows that you're (more-or-less) supposed to use it.

Comment: @ChrisW: Not to say the conclusion is wrong (or right), but note that that's sloppy reasoning, because there is plenty of public .NET functionality that *is* obsolete (say, `System.Collections.ArrayList`) or otherwise deprecated (say, `IEnumerator.Reset`).

Answer (score 0):

The most common use of downcasting in my work is due to some idiot breaking Liskov’s Substitution principle.

Imagine there’s an interface in some third party lib.

```
public interface Foo
{
     void SayHello();
     void SayGoodbye();
 }
```

And 2 classes that implement it. `Bar` and `Qux`. `Bar` is well behaved.

```
public class Bar
{
    void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“Bar says hello.”);
    }
    void SayGoodbye()
    {
         Console.WriteLine(“Bar says goodbye”);
    }
}
```

But `Qux` isn’t well behaved.

```
public class Qux
{
    void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(“Qux says hello.”);
    }
    void SayGoodbye()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Well... now I don’t have a choice. I *have* to type check and (possibly) downcast in order to avoid having my program come to a crashing halt.

Comment: Not true for this particular example. You could just catch the NotImplementedException when calling SayGoodbye.

Comment: It’s an *overly* simplified example maybe, but work with some of the older .Net APIs a bit and you’ll run into this situation. Sometimes the easiest way to write the code is to safe cast ala `var qux = foo as Qux;`.

Answer (score 0):

Another real-world example is WPF's `VisualTreeHelper`. It uses downcast to cast `DependencyObject` to `Visual` and `Visual3D`. For example, [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/VisualTreeHelper.cs,134). The downcast happens in [VisualTreeUtils.AsVisualHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/MS/Internal/Media/VisualTreeUtils.cs,331):

```
private static bool AsVisualHelper(DependencyObject element, out Visual visual, out Visual3D visual3D)
{
    Visual elementAsVisual = element as Visual;

    if (elementAsVisual != null)
    {
        visual = elementAsVisual;
        visual3D = null;
        return true;
    }

    Visual3D elementAsVisual3D = element as Visual3D;

    if (elementAsVisual3D != null)
    {
        visual = null;
        visual3D = elementAsVisual3D;
        return true;
    }            

    visual = null;
    visual3D = null;
    return false;
}
```