# Using methods specific to a subclass

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, inheritance, type-casting

I came across this SESE page: [What is a proper use of downcasting?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/366592/19237) (for C#) -- and it talks about when to downcast, and the possible downsides to it.

In Python sub classes are slightly different

**Example:**

Suppose I have the following `abstract` class:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod

class Weapon(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage

    @abstractmethod
    def prepare(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def attack(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def cleanup(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {} Damage: {}".format(self.name, self.damage)
```

and Subclass:

```
from Weapon import Weapon

class ChargeGun(Weapon):

    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        super().__init__(name, damage)

    def prepare(self):
        print("Aiming my Gun");

    def attack(self):
        print("Shooting")

    def cleanup(self):
        print("Lowering gun, and turning off laser sight")

    def charge(self):
        print("Charging Gun. Please hold..(elevator music playing)")
```

In my subclass `ChargeGun`, I have the `def charge(self):` method, and I can declare in the main a `ChargeGun` object and use it, like this:

```
cg = ChargeGun("Standard ChargeGun",5)
cg.prepare()
cg.charge()
```

If I were to introduce `Sword` as a `Weapon` subclass, the `charge(self):` would not be implemented, and `Sword` isn't even aware of it. In Python, there isn't a need to downcast or use a design pattern.

Python isn't Java/C#.

**Questions**

1. How should you be thinking when creating sub classes in languages
   like Python? Should we be thinking from an abstract point of view,
   and refactor our code?

   **Example:** `def charge(self):` could be seen as a way to prepare a `ChargeGun` so we can remove it. If I had a silencer, that's a a component of a Gun, so maybe it might make sense to have an `abstract` `WeaponComponent` class, a silencer and laser sight could be objects of that class and each would override the `def prepare(self):` method. A Sword could have a gem or stone that gives it extra strike ability, etc.

That's just one way of thinking, I'm not saying it's the best way to refactor it.

2. Is it okay to take advantage of Python's ability to use the methods of a 
   subclass directly?

Comment: Think about this from the perspective of whatever is *running* the game: how does it know what weapon it's supposed to be handling? If you end up having a whole bunch of logic like `if isinstance(weapon, ChargeGun): weapon.charge()`, I feel like that answers your question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - How then would you declare and use the `ChargeGun`, if not directly? Or are you saying don't have the `charge(self):` method?

Comment: I think you need to spend some time considering why you're bothering with an inheritance hierarchy at all. If you're going to directly instantiate and interact with your subclasses with full knowledge of which they are, it's a waste of time. The point of it is to simplify *consumers* of your instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give me an API that lets me write code like this:

```
def useWeapon(someWeapon) :
    someWeapon.charge()
    someWeapon.prepare()
    someWeapon.attack()
    someWeapon.cleanup()

useWeapon( ChargeGun("Standard ChargeGun",5) )
```

And I wont mind if `charge()` happens instantly or doesn't change the state of the weapon in anyway. I will mind if it blows up with an error or if I have to test if the weapon needs charging. Sure, this means that objects have to have knowledge of messages that seem to have nothing to do with them. But understand that the interface exists for the client that uses the weapon. Not the weapon.

If you let knowledge of what kind of weapon this is leak out suddenly the client has to KNOW what it's talking to. This is the death of polymorphism.

The favorite example is telling pets to speak. I like not having to tell a dog to bark or a duck to quack. I can just say `pet.speak()` and whatever pet that is figures out what to do. If I need my pet collection to sometimes be quiet I use a cat (otherwise known as [the null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)). You tell it to speak and it ignores you (cause it's a cat). My cat is carefully designed to quietly accept and ignore every possible message. I can send my cat anywhere and things still work nicely without blowing up. However, my pet rock is another issue. You tell my pet rock to speak and it tears a hole in the fabric of reality by complaining that it doesn't know how to speak. Now sure you can be careful and check for rocks but it's easier to use cats. They're really good at doing nothing.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, it means I should be thinking in an abstract point of view, so regardless of which `Weapon` I get I can call the necessary methods without it blowing up. Python isn't Java and so you can't say `Weapon weapon;` You would say `ChargeGun()`. How do you adjust your thinking or design with languages like that?

Comment: Python does objects just fine. Not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: What I mean is, in Java I can do `Weapon cg = new ChargeGun();` I can then write methods that take the Weapon interface or abstract class as a parameter, and it doesn't know specifically what weapon it is, just that it's going to get a `Weapon` but in Python I can't declare it the same way as in Java, I have to say `cg = ChargeGun()`

Comment: Are you talking about strong typing? Python has the same problem with pet rocks that java does. Python just waits until run time to complain about it.

Comment: Unless you use `instanceof` and check it specifically, which is a code smell.

Comment: yes, that true in either language. Once you start asking about the pet, polymorphism dies. The code turns ugly and it becomes hard to add new pets.

Comment: Can you provide an example using Python, how you would declare and use a subclass without being specific as to what weapon is being used? In other words, if you have to think in abstract terms, how would you do it in Python?

Comment: Bare with me here, how would you declare the `Weapon` that will be passed to that method? `cg = ChargeGun()` right?

Comment: Done. Maybe you'd like to read [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-apply-polymorphism-to-classes-in-python-3)

Comment: +1. And to tie it back to the OP's example, some subclasses may have an empty implementation for some of those methods. e.g., a sword doesn't need to charge anything, so it's `charge` implementation will be blank

Comment: @mmathis yes that is the point. A blank implementation (`pass`) of `charge()` on subtypes that don't need it, saves us having to check the weapon type before calling `charge()`.

Comment: @mmathis - I would refactor that code so that `def charge(self):` isn't there, as I said in my original post, it's just a way to prepare a gun for use, so `ChargeGun` would just implement the methods in the abstract class.